# Is it safe to store shell scripts into /var/www?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, public-folders

I have my apache host under `/var/www/html` and I put few small git deploy scripts into `/var/www` directory for simplicity. Is `www` a public folder? Is it safe to store scripts in there? If so, are there any risks? If not, which directory is recommended?

It is Ubuntu 14.04 server.

Comment: Who runs the scripts? In what circumstances? And do you care if the whole world can download them?

Comment: These scipts may show structure   of apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you configure your vhosts to use subdirectories within `/var/www/html` it is just as safe as to store htpasswd files in `/var/www` - no one using http will be able to read them.
A more common way is to bundle the scripts within a Webapps Folder, as shellscripts usually shouldnt contain sensitive information.